# Decile Analysis for model comparison

Tags: classification, random-forest, model-evaluation, logistic-curve

I am working on a simple classification problem (bank marketing response data) and trying various evaluation methods for multiple models to compare and understand the output.

And I was trying to do a decile analyses to compare logistic and random forest models and had one thing I wasn't completely sure.

From the logistic regression model output, we get the class probability of a customer to respond to a marketing communication.

Model output from random forest also provides some probabilities and those are basically mean of predicted outcome (probability of trees predicting 'response' for each customer).

And my question would be;

How would interpret those probabilities? (Could it be used as a measure of how confidently the model predicts? etc.)
Are those two probabilities comparable in the first place?

Comment: What is decile analysis?  The terminology implies that you are molesting the original continuous variable in some way, which would be a statistical no-no.  And note that the estimated probabilities are not measures of confidence in predictions.

Answer (score -1):

Model comparison is essential to the development of a useful predictor. There a various aspects that come into play. What you are trying to predict, is ***customer response*** just like [sales predictor](https://insight-classifiers.com/wos).

Logistic regression and random forests both ***estimate posterior probabilities*** by Bayes rule

$
\hat{P}(R \mid M)
$

with $R$ being the response and $M$ the marketing communication action. See [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479283/the-bayes-theorem-components-of-the-probability-output-of-a-classifier/479296#479296) for an explanation of Bayes rule.

When comparing the predicted outcomes the first approach is generally to threshold your posterior probabilities

$\hat{P}(R \mid M) > \hat{P}(\neg R \mid M) \Rightarrow R=Response$

whereas

$\hat{P}(R \mid M) \leq \hat{P}(\neg R \mid M) \Rightarrow \neg R=No Response$.

You first compare the number of correct predictions on your training set from logistic regression with that of random forests. What are the fractions of correct predictions? The fraction of correct predictions is called the *accuracy* and it is binomially distributed. You can compare the performance of the two accuracies using a $\chi 2$ test for two independent samples.

The probabilities $\hat{P}(R \mid M)$ are estimates and they have an underlying distribution too. The computation of $\sigma^2 [\hat{P}(R \mid M)]$ is complex but they are known for some types of predictive classifiers (specifically for linear and quadratic discriminant analysis).

A final thing is that you are performing model comparison. A general strategy is to use n-fold cross validation for that. You don't want your models to overgeneralize so eventually the accuracy needs to be computed on an independent test set as well.